# How to maintain class after button click on page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, buttonclick

I have a page in ASP .NET where when I access it, programmatically I set a value in the TextBox. When I click on the Button, I would like to update that value, but it gives me error:

> Object not defined

Here is my code:

```
public partial class InsertValues : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(); // This class contains all the querys I need to pull data

        public MyValuesClass myValues; // This is my class where I get the data from my DB

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {      
                startMyPage();  // Function that gets the values from the DataBase and sets my TextBox with the values.
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

private void startMyPage()
        {
            myValues = dataProvider.getValuesFromDB(); // Function that gets the values from a query and put them in my class, the values are. String "Banana" and Bool isNew = True

            if (!myValues.isNew) // 
            {
                txtFood.Text = myValues.food
            }
            else
            {
                myValues= new myValues();
                myValues.isNew = true;
            }
        }

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (myValues.isNew) // Object not defined. 
            {
                 dataProvider.addMyValues(myValues); // It Inserts into my DB
            }
            else
            {
                 dataProvider.editMyValues(myValues); // It Updates into my DB
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically, after I click on my "btnSave" the class **myValues** becomes null, and I get the error **Object not defined**, is there a way to maintain the class Values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refetch your `myValues` object on PostBack.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {      
        startMyPage();
    }
    else
    {
        myValues = dataProvider.getValuesFromDB();
    }
}
```

Only data that's stored in the ViewState or equivalent persistence mechanism will be kept between the initial page load and post backs, which is why values of your webforms page controls are persisted, but your code behind property isn't.

You can store things manually in the ViewState like this: `ViewState["someKey"] = someObject;`, but `someObject` has to be serializable. It looks like `myValues` is an ORM object, so it *probably* isn't serializable.

Comment: Yes, I was missing this part, really grateful. I would like to ask you only one more thing about **Only data that's stored in the ViewState or equivalent persistence mechanism will be kept between the initial page load and post backs**  I would like to learn someting more, could you provide me a link? It would be great.

Comment: Happy to help. I don't have any specific links. Try googling for persisting data in ASP .NET WebForms, ViewState and ASP .NET Sessions.

Answer (score 1):

All Variables are re-initiated at every post back. you better store your class **public MyValuesClass myValues** in session or viewstate.